# Why does my code for Ptice hit runtime error?

Tags: c++

I am new to programming and I want to learn as much as I can.
I am working on problem Ptice on Kattis ([Link to problem](https://open.kattis.com/problems/ptice)).

The problem in my programming journey now is that I create code I think works but when I pass it through Kattis it rejects my solutions halfway etc. Code below passes 3 out of 19 test cases. (on 4th case it hits a runtime error)

Would be superkind if someone could take a look why my logic isn't working / breaks. I would love to know what I do wrong so I can improve my programming. :)

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int numCharacters;
    std::string inputSequence;
    std::string 
        Adrian =
        "ABCABCABCABC",
        Bruno =
        "BABCBABCBABC",
        Goran =
        "CCAABBCCAABB";

    int pointsForAdrian = 0, pointsForBruno = 0, pointsForGoran = 0;

    std::cin >> numCharacters;
    std::cin >> inputSequence;

    for (int i = 0; i < numCharacters; i++)
    {
        if (inputSequence.at(i) == Adrian.at(i))
        {
            pointsForAdrian++;
        }
        if (inputSequence.at(i) == Bruno.at(i))
        {
            pointsForBruno++;
        }
        if (inputSequence.at(i) == Goran.at(i))
        {
            pointsForGoran++;
        }
    }

    if (pointsForAdrian >= pointsForBruno && pointsForAdrian >= pointsForGoran)
    {
        std::cout << pointsForAdrian << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Adrian" << std::endl;
    }
    
    if (pointsForBruno >= pointsForAdrian && pointsForBruno >= pointsForGoran)
    {
        if (pointsForAdrian == pointsForBruno || pointsForBruno == pointsForGoran){
            std::cout << "Bruno" << std::endl;  
        }
        else {
        std::cout << pointsForBruno << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Bruno" << std::endl;
        }

    }
    if(pointsForGoran >= pointsForAdrian && pointsForGoran >= pointsForBruno)
    {
        if (pointsForAdrian == pointsForGoran || pointsForBruno == pointsForGoran)
        {
            std::cout << "Goran" << std::endl;
        }
        else {
        std::cout << pointsForGoran << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Goran" << std::endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer sequences for the three people are each 12 characters long.

If the input string is 12 characters or less, that's fine.

But if the input string is 13 or more characters long (it can be up to 100 characters, as stated in the competition text), the line

```
if (inputSequence.at(i) == Adrian.at(i))
```

compares the input to characters past the end of your answer sequences, like this:

```
 Index:  0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
 Input:  A A A A A A A A A A  A  A  A  A  A
 Adrian: A B C A B C A B C A  B  C
```

For `i = 0` to `i = 11` everything is OK, but for `i = 12` you try to compare a character that is past Adrians string.

You would have to make your answer sequences longer for this to work, or, better yet, leave them as they are but change all three comparisons like this:

```
if (inputSequence.at(i) == Adrian.at(i % 12))
```

so it just starts over at the start of your sequence (since `12 % 12` is 0, `13 % 12` is 1, ... `i % 12` calculates the remainder of the division of `i` by 12).